# Use of undeclared type 'SignalProducerType

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I am new to ReactiveCocoa and ReactiveSwift,
I am having task of update code from Swift2 to Swift4 after updating code i stuck in one point where I encountered error for "Use of undeclared type 'SignalProducerType'" not found do we have any alternative for this ?
Please help me in resolving this issue 
i am using ReactiveCocoa 7.1.0

```
extension SignalProducerType where Value == HTTPOperationResult,Error == APIError {

    func serializeToJSON() -> SignalProducer {
        return attemptMap { result in
            guard let data = result.data else {
                return .failure(APIError.parseError("invalid json"))
            }
            guard let JSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) else {
                return .failure(APIError.parseError("invalid json"))
            }
            return .success((result,JSON))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: include your code.. your description of the problem is like super vague..

Comment: edited my question

Comment: well, ovbiously `SignalProducerType` is not a recognized type.. do you have that class somewhere?

Comment: No i don't have that class

Comment: you must have broken either something in linking/importing React, or there have been a change to API that renamed `SignalProducerType`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SignalProducerType` no longer exists. It was renamed to `SignalProducerProtocol`, but it isn't used to add operators anymore. [This ought to just be an extension on `SignalProducer` itself](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/6bdca15f7608b73cfc710828512d47542d99e656/CHANGELOG.md#signal-and-signalproducer):

> All Signal and SignalProducer operators now belongs to the respective concrete types. (#304)
>
> Custom operators should extend the concrete types directly. SignalProtocol and SignalProducerProtocol should be used only for constraining associated types.